# The test runner exited with code 9 before finishing running tests

Tags: swift, watchkit, xctest

What does code 9 signify ( and how to fix the issue ) when Xcode crashes during the execution of WatchOS tests?

Scenario:

I have an XCTestCase that reads around 100 CSV test resource files. These files are comma-delimited, have approximately 6,000 lines, and have an average size of 64K. During my test case, I  read these files into memory, and one my one, I verify that the input file ( after some processing ) matches the output file. Here is some code to demonstrate the flow:

```
import XCTest
@testable import MyWatch_Extension

class MyTest: XCTestCase {
    

    func testMyAlgo() throws {
        let testingData = discoverAvailableTestFiles(filter: "dataset_1");
        XCTAssertGreaterThan(testingData.count, 0, "have data to process")

        for (_, testingEntry) in testingData.enumerated() {
            var input : [Double] = [];
            var expectations : [Double] = [];
            readInputOutputTestData(entries: &input, fileName: testingEntry +  "_input");
            readInputOutputTestData(entries: &expectations, fileName: testingEntry + "_expected_output");
            
            // do something with the input, and store it into results
            let results = MyAglo().doSomething();

            compareResultsAndExpectations(testingEntry: testingEntry, results: results, expectations: expectations);
        }
    }

    func discoverAvailableTestFiles(filter: String) -> Set<String> {
        let bundle = Bundle(for: type(of: self))
        let paths = bundle.paths(forResourcesOfType: "csv", inDirectory: nil);
        var results = Set<String>()
        for path in paths {
            if (path.contains(filter)) {
                let fileNameSubstring = path[path.index(path.lastIndex(of: "/")!, offsetBy: 1)...]
                let qaFileName = fileNameSubstring[...fileNameSubstring.index(fileNameSubstring.lastIndex(of: "_")!, offsetBy: -1)]
                results.insert(String(qaFileName))
            }
        }
        return results;
    }

    func readInputOutputTestData(entries : inout [Double], fileName : String) {
        let bundle = Bundle(for: type(of: self))
        let path = bundle.path(forResource: fileName, ofType: "csv")!
        do {
            let data = try String(contentsOfFile: path, encoding: .utf8)
            let myStrings = data.components(separatedBy: .newlines);
            for idx in 0..<myStrings.count {
                let parts = myStrings[idx].split(separator: ",");
                if (parts.count > 0) {
                    for part in parts {
                        entries.append((part as NSString).doubleValue);
                    }
                }
            }
        } catch {
            print(error)
        }
    }
    
    func compareResultsAndExpectations(testingEntry: String, results: [Double], expectations: [Double]) {
        print("## testing \(testingEntry)");
        XCTAssertEqual(results.count, expectations.count / 3, "mismatch in data count \(testingEntry)")
        var counter = 0;
        for idx in stride(from: 0, to: expectations.count, by: 3) {
            XCTAssertEqual(results[counter], expectations[idx], accuracy: 0.5, "\(idx + 1) value mismatch")
            counter += 1;
        }
    }

}
```

When I execute the testMyAlgo testcase, I might read the first 20 files, and I get the error message :

```
The test runner exited with code 9 before finishing running tests.
```

If I run each file individually or in smaller batches ( maybe only 20 of them, as opposed to the entire loop of 100 ), everything is fine. This leads me to believe that I am exhausting the memory space of the watch or should be executing the test case differently. Any idea what the problem is, or perhaps, how I should re-structure the test case to get away from this error? ( Maybe free resources or something similar before each test case )

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can create a dumb Xcode project that runs on an iPhone and copy/paste only this test to it. If it runs OK, that means you're exceeding the limits on the watch. If that's the case, you can create a framework with your algorithm and run the tests on the framework, and import the framework on your watch extension

Comment: This is probably the best way to go, even though it doesn't get past the actual error. Thanks for sharing your thoughts.

Comment: I am no longer certain it is possible: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45498554/combined-watch-os-and-ios-framework

Comment: Quoting the comment on the answer for that link "What you could do, is share your sources between the different targets and use TargetConditionals to compile those sources with the right platforms". Still, I'm not sure how this is blocking the idea of a dumb project, since it's porpuse is only to find what the problem is